# Stretch Image of Known Ratio in OpenCV (Python) - Retaining Overall Resolution

Tags: python, opencv

I have a need to standardise a load of (A3) scans in terms of pixels. They all have the same basic template, but may have been printed by printers with slightly different settings; affecting borders and scaling in all of left-right-top-bottom dimensions. An example of how the same 'active window' might look (exaggerated, the blue bit would not contain any useful information):

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

I can work out the borders of the "white/blue" areas fine by using pixel colour scanning fine - so that's covered - but how could I essentially use this information to 'stretch' the white area of the bottom-type to match the top-type in terms of pixel-for-pixel? (At this point both types will have the same width-height resolution, so can work on that basis of commonality).

N.B. This would necessarily involve stretching and distorting the white areas of the below image, to match the top.

Comment: If the aspect ratios of the two white areas are not the same, then you have 3 choices: 1) stretch and distort to fit perfectly or 2) resize maintaining aspect by pad to fill the new area or 3) resize maintaining aspect by crop to the new area. Which do you want?

Comment: It'd be 1) stretching and distorting; so effectively the borders of the white areas in the diagrams would all match the top image - meaning all of those borders could be superimposed upon each-other exactly.

Comment: See cv2.resize() at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d. You can specify the desired output dimensions to match your larger white area.

Comment: But that seems like a simple zoom right? What I want is to tell Python to stretch the image so that X pixel from top is now in position Y, Z pixel from bottom is now in position A; instead of just being forced to zoom in and out from the center by a scale factor. For example, just resizing the bottom diagram from the question by a factor of say 1.25 wouldn't map it to look like the top diagram.

Comment: I do not understand. Do you want to fit it into the background or just resize. If you want to fit it into the blue background, then resize to the larger white and then insert it using numpy into a blue background image or into the larger image.

Comment: Is there no more efficient / less long winded programatically way to do that resize? As surely that would involve 1) Cropping an image to involve just the active area ('white bit' in bottom image), 2) Resizing that active area to match the dimensions required ('white bit' in top image), 3) Creating a blank array of the size of the whole top image (i.e. including the blue bit), 4) Inserting the output from part 2 and filling down from the coordinates of the top-left border of the above image's white area?

Comment: You could find the corners via corner detection or contours bounding box for the white areas. Then do an affine or perspective to resize, then crop to the larger blue dimensions.